# My function Java didn't work with DB (MySQL) using Struts 2

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, struts2

I have some problem with my code it didn't work I think this problem in my class `UserService` but I'm not sure. When I run my program my console shows:

**Stacktraces:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.web.actions.UtlisateurAction.listUsers(UtlisateurAction.java:67)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:450)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:289)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:252)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DeprecationInterceptor.intercept(DeprecationInterceptor.java:41)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:167)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:254)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:254)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:139)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:562)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:151)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    
You are seeing this page because development mode is enabled. Development mode, or devMode, enables extra debugging behaviors and reports to assist developers. To disable this mode, set:

  struts.devMode=false
in your WEB-INF/classes/struts.properties file.
```

**`UtlisateurAction.java`:**

```
package com.web.actions;

import java.util.List;

import com.app.business.bo.security.Role;
import com.app.business.bo.security.Utlisateur;
import com.app.business.services.UtlisateurService;
import com.app.exceptions.DuplicateLoginException;
import com.web.BaseAction;

public class UtlisateurAction extends BaseAction {



    private UtlisateurService userService;

    private List<Utlisateur> listUsers;

    private Utlisateur utilisateur;

    private List<Role> listRoles;

    private Long selectedRole;


    public String passage(){
        System.out.println("Passage");
    return SUCCESS;
    }
    public String showMenu(){
        System.out.println("User Access");
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String initFormAddUser() {
        listRoles = userService.getAllRoles();

        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String addUser() {

        try {
            utilisateur.setRole(userService.getRoleById(selectedRole));
            userService.addUtilisateur(utilisateur);

        } catch (DuplicateLoginException ex) {
            addActionError("Operation non effectuee a  cause d'une erreur");

            ex.printStackTrace();
            return "error";

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            addActionError("Operation non effectuee Ã  cause d'une erreur");

            ex.printStackTrace();
            return "error";

        }
        // on affiche une page d'erreur
        addActionMessage("Utilisateur ajoutée avec succées");
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String listUsers() {
        System.out.println("On train de detecter");
        listUsers = userService.getAllUsers();
        System.out.println("GET ALL USERS");
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public List<Utlisateur> getListUsers() {
        return listUsers;
    }

    public void setListUsers(List<Utlisateur> listUsers) {
        this.listUsers = listUsers;
    }

    public UtlisateurService getUserService() {
        return userService;
    }

    public void setUserService(UtlisateurService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    public Utlisateur getUtilisateur() {
        return utilisateur;
    }

    public void setUtilisateur(Utlisateur utilisateur) {
        this.utilisateur = utilisateur;
    }

    public List<Role> getListRoles() {
        return listRoles;
    }

    public void setListRoles(List<Role> listRoles) {
        this.listRoles = listRoles;
    }

    public Long getSelectedRole() {
        return selectedRole;
    }

    public void setSelectedRole(Long selectedRole) {
        this.selectedRole = selectedRole;
    }

}
```

**`UtlisateurServiceImpl.java`:**

```
package com.services.impl;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException;
import org.springframework.orm.ObjectRetrievalFailureException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;

import com.bo.security.Role;
import com.bo.security.Utilisateur;
import com.boudaa.dao.exceptions.EntityNotFoundException;
import com.dao.RoleDao;
import com.dao.UtilisateurDao;
import com.exceptions.DuplicateLoginException;
import com.services.UtilisateurService;

public class UtilisateurServiceImpl implements UtilisateurService, UserDetailsService {

    private UtilisateurDao userDao;
    private RoleDao roleDao;

    protected final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String pLogin) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Utilisateur lUser = null;
        Collection<GrantedAuthority> arrayAuths = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

        // On rÃ©cupÃ¨re un objet de domaine de type User ayant comme login pLogin
        try {
            lUser = userDao.getUserByLogin(pLogin);

        } catch (ObjectRetrievalFailureException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();

            // nous relanÃ§ons une UsernameNotFoundException si aucun utilisateur
            // ne correspond Ã  cet login
            log.debug("Erreur d'authentification avec le login : " + pLogin);
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User " + pLogin + " not exists", ex);

        }


        // Si un utilisateur correspond Ã  cet identifiant, nous en profitons
        // pour mettre Ã  jour sa date de derniÃ¨re connexion
        lUser.setLastAccessDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        userDao.update(lUser);
        // Il faut ensuite rÃ©cupÃ©rer les rÃ´les de lâ€™utilisateur et les
        // mettre
        // sous la forme de SimpleGrantedAuthority, une interface propre Ã 
        // Spring
        // Security*

        Role role = lUser.getRole();
        arrayAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRoleName()));
        // /un User (classe Spring Security) est crÃ©Ã©
        System.out.println("oui");
        return new User(pLogin, lUser.getPassword(), lUser.isEnabled(), lUser.isAccountNotExpired(), true,
                lUser.isAccountNotLocked(), arrayAuths);
    }


    public Utilisateur getUserByLogin(String pLogin) throws EntityNotFoundException {

        List<Utilisateur> users;
        try {
            users = userDao.getEntityByColumn("Utilisateur", "login", pLogin);

        } catch (ObjectRetrievalFailureException ex) {

            throw new EntityNotFoundException("Aucun utilisateur avec le login : " + pLogin);
        }

        if (users.size() != 1) {
            // TODO : Ecrire le code pour ajouter des log fatal
            // TODO : ecrire le code envoyant un mail d'erreur fatal Ã 
            // l'administrateur

            throw new RuntimeException("Erreur inconnue dans le systeme");
        }

        return users.get(0);
    }
    public void addUtilisateur(Utilisateur user) throws DuplicateLoginException {

        // pour hacher avec SHA1
        ShaPasswordEncoder encoder = new ShaPasswordEncoder();


        // Hachage du mot de passe avec un gain de sel variable = login
        String cryptedPassword = encoder.encodePassword(user.getPassword(),
                user.getLogin());

        // affecter le mot de passe hachÃ©
        user.setPassword(cryptedPassword);

        // stockage de l'utilisateur dans la base de donnÃ©es
        try {
            userDao.create(user);

        } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException ex) {
            log.error("erreur d'ajout d'un utilisateur Ã  cause de l'exception " + ex
                    + " . un utilisateur avec le login " + user.getLogin() + " existe dÃ©jÃ  dans la base de donnÃ©es");
            throw new DuplicateLoginException("Erreur d'inscription, login existe dÃ©jÃ ", ex);
        }

    }

    public Role getRoleByName(String roleName) {
        return roleDao.getRoleByName(roleName);
    }

    public Role getRoleById(Long pRoleId) throws EntityNotFoundException {
        return roleDao.findById(pRoleId);
    }

    public List<Utilisateur> getAllUsers() {
        return userDao.getAll();
    }

    public List<Role> getAllRoles() {
        return roleDao.getAll();
    }

    public void deleteUser(Utilisateur u) throws EntityNotFoundException {

        userDao.delete(u.getIdUtilisateur());

    }

    public UtilisateurDao getUserDao() {
        return userDao;
    }

    public void setUserDao(UtilisateurDao userDao) {
        this.userDao = userDao;
    }

    public RoleDao getRoleDao() {
        return roleDao;
    }

    public void setRoleDao(RoleDao roleDao) {
        this.roleDao = roleDao;
    }


}
```

Comment: Do you ever set `userService` to anything?  It looks to me like it's probably still `null` at the time you try to use it in `listUsers`.

Comment: In `UtlisateurAction` class, can you replace `listUsers()` method with the below snippet and try?
`public String listUsers() {
        System.out.println("On train de detecter");
        listUsers = new UtlisateurService().getAllUsers();
        System.out.println("GET ALL USERS");
        return SUCCESS;
    }`

Comment: Thanks but i m working with spring ,he manage instance

Comment: I still don't believe that your `userService` has been injected.  Possibly because you don't have the right Spring annotation.  You could use your debugger to check this.

Comment: Post your`applicationContext.xml`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like if the bean id is available in `applicationContext.xml` then it will be injected to the action bean. Otherwise `null` values expected when beans remains uninitialized.

For integration struts with spring you need [struts-spring-plugin](https://struts.apache.org/docs/spring-plugin.html).

> Spring is a lightweight container, providing centralized, automated
>   configuration and wiring of your application objects, using a
>   technique called **"Dependency Injection"**
>
> The Spring Plugin works by overriding the Struts `ObjectFactory` to
>   enhance the creation of core framework objects. When an object is to
>   be created, it uses the class attribute in the Struts configuration to
>   correspond to the id attribute in the Spring configuration. If not
>   found, the class will try to be created as usual, then be autowired by
>   Spring. In the case of Actions, Spring 2's bean scope feature can be
>   used to scope an Action instance to the session, application, or a
>   custom scope, providing advanced customization above the default
>   per-request scoping.
>
> Spring Actions are Optional!